# as3 iso instances lost their scope in a loaded swf

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, instance

I have an shell that loads up other swf and runs them.

When publish the shell to IOS (air 26) several swfs(published as as3/ flash player 20) don't register movie clips and appear as null.

Everything works fine when i publish to web.

The work around i have found is that i need to change in the loaded swfs.

Example 1
From:

```
switch (evt.target) {
        case go_btn:
            play();
            break;
}
```

To:

```
switch (evt.target.name) {
        case 'go_btn':
            play();
            break;
}
```

Example 2 From:

```
tween.to(shakeMe22, 1, {y: shakeMe22.y+3});
```

To:

```
this.shakeMe22 = this['shakeMe22'];
tween.to(this.shakeMe22, 1, {y: this.shakeMe22.y+3});
```

What is dumbfounding is that some of the loaded swfs work fine. 
A simple example of the the problem is I create a MC, droped it in and give it a instance name "randomMC.

The trace(randomMC) return null (on Ipad / debugger mode).

What am i missing?

Comment: Weird, I agree. I think you should study https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html through thoroughly. There are several remarks about iOS differences. Also AFAIK **this.shakeMe22 = this['shakeMe22']** should have no effect as both left and right sides are different ways to do the same thing. Probably **this.shakeMe22** works event without the assignment above.

Comment: Some of the results i was having were unbelievable. I had 2 MCs instance name  = shakeMe1 and shakeMe2.  
trace(shakeMe1.name)// "shakeMe2",
trace(shakeMe2)  // null

Comment: It might be a good idea to work through **getChildByName(...)** then, it will work as intended with no regard to declaration mess.